# How many solutions exist for a matrix equation $A^2=I$?

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order three or two, and $I$ be a unit matrix. How many solutions are possible for the equation $$A^2=I$$?
 In case the solutions are infinite, or very large, how do I check, without actual multiplication, if a given matrix is a solution to the given equation. In the general case, what about a factorisable matrix polynomial equation?

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/when-is-a-matrix-the-inverse-of-itself/

Comment: Yes, probably the page talks about orthogonal matrix. But this solves only the given matrix equation. What about an equation like $A^3-3A^2+2I=0$?

Comment: Are you trying to solve it for the real or complex numbers?

Comment: Could somebody provide an easier solution, I mean one that uses less advanced concepts, say high school concepts? Or is it that these concepts are necessary.  The problem is rather an elementary one. @fabian, for now I'm working on matrices with real elements.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44341/finding-number-of-matrices-whose-square-is-the-identity-matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix $A$ will satisfy $p(A)=0$ for a polynomial $p$ if and only if the [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29) of $A$ divides $p$.

In your case, we have $p(x) = x^2 - 1$.  So, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be $x^2-1,x-1,$ or $x+1$.  In any case, we can say

> $A^2 = I$ if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues $1$ or $-1$

In the size $2$ case, we have $A=I,A=-I$, or 
$$
A = 
S\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}S^{-1}
$$
to check whether $A$ is one of these last matrices, we can verify that trace$(A) = 0$ and $\det(A) = -1$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice in general (unless the field is finite) there could be uncountably infinite many solutions even for $2\times 2
$ matrices, e.g. 
$$\forall c\in\mathbb R:A=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
c & -1 \\
\end{array} \right) $$