# prove that $A^2 = I $ implies that $A=I $ or $ A= -I $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do we prove the above proposition?
$(AA)(ij)=1$ for  $i=j$ , $0$ for $i\ne j $.
So, $[AA]_{ij} = \sum_k [A]_{ik} [A]_{kj}$.
How can I proceed from this point?

Comment: What about $$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: Over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic not equal to $2$, there are exactly $n+1$ matrices, up to conjugacy, of dimension $n\times n$ which satisfy the condition.  If $\text{char}\,\mathbb{K}=2$, then there are exactly $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1$ matrices, up to conjugacy, of dimension $n\times n$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106070/if-a2-i-identity-matrix-then-a-pm-i and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44341/finding-number-of-matrices-whose-square-is-the-identity-matrix

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is diagonal matrix then $A^2$ is diagonal with diagonal elements squares of diagonal elements of $A$...

Consider

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

and many more..

Answer (score 1):

This is not generally true. It only implies that $A = A^{-1}$, i.e., that $A$ is its own inverse.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: @MichaelHardy $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily true. You should attempt to find a counter example in 2x2 matrices.